# Referencing other bean values from within custom constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, jersey-2.0, bean-validation

I am using the Hibernate Validator for my project. I would like to use a custom constraint to reference another field from the bean inside the constraint validator implementation. How is this possible?

Bean

```
@NotNull(when="mvel:this.two == null")
private String one;

@NotNull(when="mvel:this.one == null")
private String two;
```

Validator

```
public class NotNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotNull, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        //how do I get access to the parent bean here??
    }
}
```

I am using Hibernate 5.0.0, Jersey 2.6, JBoss 5, Java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot. The current context information available for a field validation does not give you access to the whole bean instance. At least not for now. There are discussions around adding the root bean to the context, but as per Bean Validation spec the root bean is not available. The reason behind this is that some methods of the *Validator* do not have an bean instance (`validateValue`). A constraint might then pass or fail depending on which validation method is used.

If you want to compare/reference multiple fields you will need a custom class level constraint.